# how to pass a function as parameter in a vue directive

Tags: vue.js

in react and jsx I would use curly braces to pass nested functions and their params, as parameters. but since there is this quote syntax in vue js, I am confused.

what I'm trying to do is something like this:

`<span @click="myFirstFunction( ()=> console.log('param') )" />`

```
myFirstFunction(code){
                code();   
            
            }
```

actually, this is the simplified version
what I'm trying to do is to save that code in an state and run it in other situations

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you describe `myFirstFunction()` method?

Comment: what is `code` type? function or string?

Comment: Code type is a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your syntax is correct. But in your simple example, you are trying to access a `property` or a `data` which is not defined. You may think `console` is a global object it should be accessed from anywhere, but no. You can only access component properties (data, methods, etc.) from the **`template`** in VUE. So you should do something like below to access the console or any other global object:

```
 data() {
    return {
      console: Object,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.console = console;
  },
```

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-hill-d4ygb?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:298-402)

Answer (score 0):

### You should do either

```
<span @click="() => console.log('param')" />
```

### or

```
<span @click="myFirstFunction" />
```

myFirstFunction should be defined as a method.

```
methods: {
  myFirstFunction() {
     // your function
  }
}
```